# OAuth Java connection on continues streaming

Tags: java, oauth, scribe

```
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                          .provider(TradeKingApi.class)
                          .apiKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
                          .apiSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET).build();
Token accessToken = new Token(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL);
service.signRequest(accessToken, request);

request.setConnectionKeepAlive(true);
```

I will get stream continiously... in this case how i can close the connection

Can u please help me on this regard

Comment: request.setConnectionKeepAlive(false);  ?

Comment: it's a streaming api? like Twitter's? Seriously you should explain yourself better, I'm the author of the library and cant figure for my life what you mean here.

Comment: we are using twitter API but in one case i want to close the connection how i can do that  thanks for your response..